# Matlab bsxfun alternative cause wrong result

Tags: arrays, matlab, bsxfun

I have to run  Matlab code on an old version that doesn't support `bsxfun` and need to write the equivalent expression of

```
matx = bsxfun(@rdivide, matx, reshape(f, 1, 1, length(f)));
```

I have tried this

```
matx=matx./ones(size(reshape(f, 1, 1, length(f)),1));
```

but I get wrong result

`matx` size is 246x301x81
`f` size is 1x81 before the invocation of the istruction that use bsxfun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `matx` is a 3D array and `f` is a row vector of length equal to the number of elements in `dim-3` of `matx`, you can perform the [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) equivalent expansion/replication with `repmat` and then perform elementwise division like so -

```
% Get size of matx
[m1,n1,r1] = size(matx);

%// Replicate f to the size of matx and perform elementwise division
matx = matx./repmat(permute(f,[1 3 2]),[m1 n1 1])
```

Comment: With your edited code now I get this error  `Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.`

Comment: @AndreaF Try this instead: `matx = matx./reshape(f(ones(m1*n1,1),:),[m1 n1 r1])`?

Comment: same error on reshape also with `matx = matx./reshape(f(ones(m1*n1,1),:),[m1 n1 r1])`

Comment: @AndreaF You said `matx` is `246x301x81` and `f` is `1x81` right? So, with that, `f(ones(m1*n1,1),:)` must be `246x 301x 81`, could you confirm this for me? When that is confirmed, `reshape(f(ones(m1*n1,1),:),[m1 n1 r1])` mustn't throw any error. Also, please add these size info into the question.

Comment: I confirm  that matx is 246x301x81 and f is 1x81 ...but the error happens and get the message `Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.`

Comment: @AndreaF Sorry, I meant `size(f(ones(m1*n1,1),:))` must be `74046 x 81`, could you confirm this?

Comment: @AndreaF I think you have reported wrong size of `f` to me. You said `f` is `1 x 81`, but I think it might be `81 x 1`. So, for that you need to do `matx = matx./reshape(f(:,ones(m1*n1,1)).',m1,n1,r1);` instead. Would this work?

Comment: I have checked f size again and confirm that is 1x81, I have tried to use also `matx = matx./reshape(f(:,ones(m1*n1,1)).',m1,n1,r1);` and get the same error on reshape

Comment: @AndreaF Let me ask you two things - What's the MATLAB version are you on that doesn't have bsxfun? And, do you have [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) included in your MATLAB version?

Comment: actally I'm not in the laboratory so I cannot say exactly what is the version, but I suppose repmat should be included since is older than bsxfun

Comment: any news? how to use repmat to replace the bsxfun?

Comment: @AndreaF Try: `matx = matx./repmat(permute(f,[1 3 2]),[m1 n1 1])`.

Comment: @AndreaF Not sure if you tried with the edited code - `matx = matx./repmat(permute(f,[1 3 2]),[m1 n1 1])`, try again?

Comment: Ok. (Is slow as the hell) but finally works! thank you so much for the time that you have dedicated to help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @AndreaF Yeah, that's why `bsxfun` is preferred! Much relieved to hear that it finally worked! Let's delete all the earlier comments, as it would confuse future readers? I will edit the answer with the code version that worked.